# Модификатор virtual деструктора в С++

Tags: c++

Есть код

```
class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass();
    virtual ~TestClass();
    // ...
}
```

Что означает такая запись? В каких случаях необходимо добавлять модификатор virtual к деструкторам?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть хорошее правило в C++: если предполагаете наследование от класса, делайте его деструктор виртуальным.
Это нужно, чтобы предотвратить возможные утечки памяти.

Предположим, мы объявили наследника TestClass:

```
class TestSubclass: public TestClass {
public:
    TestSubclass();
    virtual ~TestSubclass();
private:
    int someVariable; // новый член класса
}
```

И написали такой код:

```
TestClass* variable = new TestSubclass();
...
delete variable;
```

В конструкции delete должен вызываться деструктор, причем он трактуется здесь как обычный метод, и если он невиртуальный, то он определяется статически (во время компиляции) на основании объявленного типа. Таким образом, если бы мы не объявили деструктор TestClass виртуальным, то:

1. вызывался бы ~TestClass(), а не ~TestSubclass();
2. освободилось sizeof(TestClass) байт памяти, память из-под someVariable не освободилась бы и мы получили бы утечку памяти.

А с виртуальным деструктором все хорошо, а именно:

1. последовательно вызываются деструкторы ~TestSubclass() и ~TestClass();
2. освобождается ровно столько памяти, сколько на самом деле занимает объект, то есть sizeof(TestSubclass).

Answer (score 2):

Не vitrual, а virtual. Ключевое слово virtual нужно для вызова деструкторов наследуемых классов при удалении объекта базового класса через оператор delete. Виртуальный деструктор добавляет 4 байта к размеру класса. Если объекты классов cоздаются не в динамической памяти, а на cтеке, то компилятор знает иерархию классов и все деструкторы будут вызваны независимо от наличия virtual.